# How to undo a failed SSD install

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, battery, boot

Yesterday, I tried to install a Kingston SSD that I've bought, in place of my Acer Aspire M5-581TG-73516G52Mss's "existing" 20gb SSD. There were a few issues, however:

- The laptop did not contain a SSD anywhere inside it, even though it appears in all OS's run on the pc, and data has been stored on it (and operated at a SSD's speed)
- As a given, I didn't end up installing my purchased SSD, and am planning on getting a caddy for it.
- Since then, the Windows boot time on the primary 500gb HDD is about three times slower than before the *upgrade*.
- The battery only functions at specific angles, and not always even at those angles; which suggests a loose connection. All connections running out of the battery pack are secure.

I am at my wits end, I have no idea how these issues came about, or how to fix them; so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Bumping.

Comment: You have a hybrid drive. It's a mechanical HDD that caches on a small SSD, likely built into the drive itself or as mSATA. You may have changed a BIOS setting to disable this function or you may have deleted the cache. The drive's firmware should figure out what to cache in time.

Comment: I thought so too, but the drive's specifications say nothing about a hybrid SSD. Is that common?

Comment: The easiest way to tell, is to get the 4 digit product number from the back of the device. This particular model has several different versions, denoted by M5-581-TG-**XXXX**. The bold characters are the model. Should look something like this: http://global-download.acer.com/SupportFiles/images/Help/faq_01.jpg

Comment: The full product model is M5-581TG-73516G52Mss